# Help Simplifying a Commutator Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

For the SHO, our teacher told us to scale
$$p\rightarrow \sqrt{m\omega\hbar} ~p$$
$$x\rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega}}~x$$
And then define the following
$$K_1=\frac 14 (p^2-q^2)$$
$$K_2=\frac 14 (pq+qp)$$
$$J_3=\frac{H}{2\hbar\omega}=\frac 14(p^2+q^2)$$
The first part is to show that
$$Q \equiv -K_1^2-K_2^2+J_3^2$$
IS a number.  My approach:
$$16Q=J_3^2-K_1^2-K_2^2=(p^2+q^2)^2-(p^2-q^2)^2-(pq+qp)^2$$
$$=p^4+q^4+p^2q^2+q^2p^2-(p^4+q^4-p^2q^2-q^2p^2)-((pq)^2+(qp)^2+pqqp+qpqp)$$
$$=2p^2q^2+2q^2p^2-pqpq-qpqp-pqqp-qppq$$
At least point, I am unsure of how to simplify any further.  A lot of these look like the form of anticommutators, which does not seem to provide any useful information in turning Q into a number.  Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT::

This is how far I have gotten.
[image]

Comment: As a terminological note (because I remember being confused by this), what is meant by "Q is a number" is that "Q is a number multiplied by the identity operator."

Comment: You should post questions, not topics... This is a question and answer website, not a forum.

Comment: Hint to the notes (v3): If you start from $p^2q^2$ (and its other orderings), and reduce via the CCR, you can only get terms $p^2q^2$, $i\hbar pq$, and $\hbar^2$ (and their other orderings). Putting $\hbar=1$, one could potentially get a term $(pq)^2$, but never get a term $i(pq)^2$ like you have in your notes.

Comment: I redid it noticing that I accidentally carried that i(pq)^2 incorrectly.  I still end up with an operator term that isnt a c number

Comment: Okay.  I think I solved it out.  Did you happen to do it out as well and find that this results in -1?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $pq$-order$^1$ your last expression $$2(p^2q^2+q^2p^2)-(pq+qp)^2.$$ $pq$-ordering means commuting all $p$'s to the left and all the $q$'s to the right by using$^2$ the [CCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) formula $qp = pq +i\hbar{\bf 1}$, possibly repeatedly. (There are shorter ways, but $pq$-ordering is at least a systematic approach.) What remains will be a $c$-number. In fact, the result is $-3\hbar^2{\bf 1}$.

--

$^1$ Or alternatively, $qp$-order your last expression.

$^2$ Here is an example of the $pq$-ordering procedure: $ qp^n = p^nq +i\hbar n p^{n-1}$.

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean

Comment: For example, $qp = pq+[q,p]$?

Comment: Yes, that is an example of commuting a $p$ to the left. Everytime time you see a product $qp$ in your last formula, substitute in the right hand side of that equation for $qp$.

Comment: So what about a case of qpqp, would that go to (pq+[q,p])(pq+[q,p])

Comment: Yes, and then you will have 1 c-number, two two-operator terms with all $p$'s on the left and $q$'s on the right, but then you will have a four operator term which is not $pq$ ordered. You will need to make your substition again to move the last $p$ through the $q$.

Comment: I also have a term that is p^2 q^2, how does that turn into a c number?

Comment: additionally, can this be an imaginary number?>

Comment: Im going through very careffully and I end up with 2pqqp-2+1

Comment: @yankeefan11: It does become a $c$-number. Try again.

Comment: I added a picture of my math.  Do you see any errors in minus signs or anything?