# Anticommutator difference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator, anticommutator

> What is the value of this difference of anticommutators $$\{x^2,p^2\}-(\{x,p\}^2)/2$$ if the commutator $$[x,p]=i\hbar ~?$$

I have tried and obtained a value $$-3\hbar^2/2 - 2i\hbar px.$$ But the answer given is $-3\hbar^2/2$. I cannot decide whether I am wrong or the answer given is wrong.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98635/2451

Comment: Could you show us your work?  It would make it easier for us to tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: Please note that Physics.SE is *not* a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714).

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake somewhere. My approach was to write 
$xp=i\hbar +px$
and $px=xp-i\hbar$ on the side of my paper and just substitute away. I first wrote
$$\{x^2,p^2\}-\frac{(\{x,p\})^2}{2}=x^2p^2+p^2x^2-\frac{xpxp+xp^2x+px^2p+pxpx}{2}$$
The terms in the fraction are
$$xpxp=x^2p^2-i\hbar xp$$
$$xp^2x=x^2p^2-2i\hbar xp$$
$$px^2p=x^2p^2-2i\hbar xp$$
$$pxpx=x^2p^2-2i\hbar xp-i\hbar px$$
So the numerator is
$$xpxp+xp^2x+px^2p+pxpx=4x^2p^2-7i\hbar-i\hbar px$$
Now add and subtract $i\hbar xp$ so we get a commutator
$$4x^2p^2-8i\hbar+(i\hbar xp-i\hbar px)=4x^2p^2-8i\hbar xp-\hbar^2$$
We thus get 
$$-x^2p^2+p^2x^2+4i\hbar xp+\frac{\hbar^2}{2}$$
Some more substitutions give
$$x^2p^2=2i\hbar xp+2i\hbar px+p^2x^2$$
So all the quadratic terms cancel. We end up with
$$2i\hbar xp -2i\hbar px+\frac{\hbar^2}{2}=-2\hbar^2+\frac{\hbar^2}{2}=-\frac{3\hbar^2}{2}$$
as was to be shown.

Comment: $2i\hbar-2i\hbar px=-2\hbar^2$. How?

Comment: @Purushothaman I fixed that typo a while ago. It is supposed to read $2i\hbar xp-2i\hbar px=-2\hbar^2$.